# Radical of an ideal.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> How can I compute $\sqrt{(x^2+y^2-1,yz-1)}$ as ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$?

Actually I have to prove that $(x^2+y^2-1,yz-1)$ is prime but I don't know how.
Could you give me some suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have isomorphisms of rings 
$$
\mathbb C[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2-1,yz-1) \simeq \left( \mathbb C[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1) \right)_y
$$
where the index $y$ denotes localization (recall that in a ring $R$, if $f \in R$, then the localization $R_f$ can be constructed as the quotient $R[x]/(xf-1)$). Since the localization of an integral domain at a non-zero element is again an integral domain, it suffices to show that $x^2 + y^2 -1$ generates a prime ideal ; since $\mathbb C[x,y]$ is a UFD, it suffices to show that $x^2 + y^2 -1$ is irreducible. Can you do that?

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it could be seen in terms of localization. Anyway at the moment I cannot show that $x^2+y^2-1$ is irreducible, so i need to think about it.

Comment: @aleio1 : it's really really really particular to the polynomial $yz-1$, so in some sense "you got lucky" (or the person who wrote the exercise thought in terms of localization!). Try thinking about how this polynomial would look like if it factored and show that this way cannot happen! I'll let you ponder a bit.

Comment: I've done, it is irreducible. I forced to have the identity $(ax+by+c)(\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma)=x^2+y^2-1$ and i obtained an impossible system of equations. Hope i did in the right way.

Comment: @aleio1 : Good! You did the commutative-algebraic answer, I assume (i.e. just working out the coefficients with equations). A more fun way to prove it (perhaps you're not there yet, but it's always fun to know) is that if you take the projective closure of the affine curve $x^2 + y^2 -1$ in $\mathbb P^2_{\mathbb C}$, you obtain the curve given by the homogeneous equation $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0$.

Comment: This can be seen to be a smooth conic (by the Jacobian criterion for instance, which in this case tells us that the tangent space has dimension $1$ at every point!), and since two lines in the projective plane always intersect, a union of two lines has a singular point. Therefore your conic is not a union of two lines!

Comment: Thank you very much @Patrick. That's a really interesting point of view even if I am not able to produce such arguments at this time. But I appreciate your help :)

Comment: @aleio1 : It'll come!